# Tools for analyzing cachegrind files in aggregate?

Tags: php, profiling, xdebug, kcachegrind

Are there any tools that can analyze a folder full of xdebug dumps in aggregate?

When we enabled Xdebug profiling on our production server for short periods of time, we always end up with hundreds of files, that takes a lot of time to analyze individually in WinCacheGrind or KCacheGrind. I am looking for a tool that can be used in aggregate, to tell me which functions take up the most time in all of the files combined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use config directive **xdebug.profiler_append** instead

When this setting is set to 1, profiler files will not be overwritten when a new request would map to the same file (depending on the xdebug.profiler_output_name setting. Instead the file will be appended to with the new profile.

(http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler)

Comment: Is there a good reason the *xdebug.profiler_append* flag doesn't appear on that page, or any other documentation I can find? It appears to be a hidden config flag. Is it unsupported?

Comment: Scroll down to "Related Settings"